# Delphi - multiple remote com objects

Tags: delphi, com, guid, dcom

My D5 application is on a server being used remotely by a couple of users, so I need use the following function to create a COM object to launch another application (LmPos) installed back on that users PC upon launch:

```
CreateRemoteComObject(const MachineName: WideString; const ClassID: TGUID): IUnknown;
```

rather than creating a local COM object as before:

```
EposServer := CreateOLEObject('POS.Server');
```

However, the MachineName and ClassID to connect to will depend on which users is launching this application. I see two problems with this...

The parameters must be constant, so how can I assign them variable? Or is this impossible as they're constants.

If I demand user input, how do I convert the String in to a TGUID? It only seems to accept the format := '{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx etc}'

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not even sure if this is possible at present, I'm attempting to configure DCOM but not succeeding.

Comment: If you've put a shortcut from a share on a machine and running the application from there, you're not remoting anything, create a local COM object.  You can pass variables as const parameters. See [`StringToGUID`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_StringToGUID.html).

Comment: @Sertac, if the question here is `How do I convert the String into a TGUID ?` then your comment is the answer ;)

Comment: @TLama - Looking at the title, I'd say, I don't have a clear idea what the question is.. Thanks for the vote :)

Comment: The StringToGUID function is useful thanks, but I do need a remote COM object. Users need to be able to remotely connect to a server, run the (Bookings) application, which creates a remote COM link back to the users PC to launch a local (Point of Sale) application. Apparently it works faster this way...

Comment: @notidaho `...The parameters must be constant, so how can I assign them variable? ` Just assign any valid value to the parameters, which the parameters are marked as `const` doesn't mean it can't be a variable value, it just means the compiler won't let you directly change it and is only ever read by the `CreateRemoteComObject` procedure. So you can use something like this `CreateRemoteComObject(MachineName,StringToGUID('{CA82B1FB-3D6C-4C16-871B-A6808A4D9F3A}')) ` whitou tproblems.

Comment: ok thanks, I've set it up OK. Now it's a question of get the remote machine to accept the call. Currently I get the message "Server execution Failed"

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the DCOM remote application on server will always run with the current user logged, as you stated.

Get rid of DCOM if you can. It is a deprecated technology, and Windows Seven and 2008 Server do not like it. You'll need to force SMB 1 protocol on PCs, and even with that, we had a lot of problems.

I faced a similar issue recently with some Delphi 5 pool of applications. I converted the DCOM calls of existing Delphi 5 applications into a HTTP service, using [http.sys kernel-mode server](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/11/HTTP-server-using-fast-http.sys-kernel-mode-server) running in a Windows service (launched at server startup, even before any user is logged on), and [WinHTTP](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/07/04/WinINet-vs-WinHTTP) for the client, which mimics the initial DCOM class (so on the client only one unit changed). Since HTTP is stateless, in order to push events from the server to the clients, I added a timer-based query in the client class, to retrieve any pending event from the server (a 500 ms timing is enough and efficient). This solution worked like a charm with Delphi 5 existing code, and the final customers just like the result in terms of speed and stability.

Comment: thanks Arnaud. Does this method require anything different in the code but CreateRemoteComObject, otherwise I can suggest it to the IT on site. Obviously this isn't ideal customer service but it seems abit over my head for just for one client.

Comment: @notidaho Of course, this may lead into a lot of code rewrite, if you have a lot of DCOM classes to convert. In my case, there was just one, so it was easy to do. With such a solution, you don't use DCOM any more. But you'll have to rewrite some part of both your server and client code. This is not just an IT issue - even if ITs will definitively prefer seeing HTTP packets on the network instead of DCOM.

Comment: Wrong: the remote application server will run with the user you specify in DCOMCnfg.exe - same properties can be set when you install the server using the proper registry settings. Many issues with DCOM stems from its complexity, scarce documentation, and lack of knowledge by the developer/user. I'd would get rid of D5 before DCOM. D5 is the really old technology here.