# Datasnap/DCOM on Windows Web Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, delphi, dcom, datasnap

The same setup works on Windows 7 / 64 Bit and Windows Server 2008 / 64 Bit:

- the Datasnap server application is located on a mounted network drive
- registered with tregsvr `<drive>:\path\to\server.exe` (as Administrator)
- the GUID is shown in dcomcnfg
- Socketserver and DCOM services are running

The client fails with the error message "Class not registered"

If I move the server app to a local directory, and repeat the tregsvr registration, the client can connect without problems.

What else could I check?

Comment: **Beware** of socket server: 1) Everything is run in the security context of the scktsrv.exe service user (don't run it as localsystem!) 2) It does not support 64 bit integers correctly. It will overwrite memory and return the wrong result. Use plain DCOM especially if you're in a LAN and don't need to communicate across a single TCP/IP port because of firewalls or the like.

Comment: @ldsandon it is a legacy system which can not be replaced soon. Socketserver used to be advertised as a nice way to access MIDAS (now Datasnap) servers when it was introduced, and we used it. Now it seems to be something like the BDE :)

Comment: Get rid of DCOM if you can. It is a deprecated technology, and Windows Seven and 2008 Server do not like it. You'll need to force SMB 1 protocol on PCs, and even with that, we had a lot of problems. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647289/delphi-multiple-remote-com-objects/7661651#7661651 about how I replaced it with a HTTP service, for several Delphi 5 applications at once.

Comment: @Arnaud thank you (DCOM is history), we will move to HTTP too soon

Comment: I'm using DCOM with 7 and 2008 R2 without issues. If it didn't work, a lot of Windows tools themselves won't work - many remote administration tools work via RPC or DCOM. No need to force SMB1, which doesn't make sense. And DCOM is tightly integrated with AD security, while HTTP is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the client allowed to connect to the network drive? Since the client is in fact initiating the startup of the server, it should be able to read that network drive (which is exactly what you are seeing, since it works fine if the server is on a local drive)...

Comment: IIUC client connects to the Borland Socketserver first, which then launches the DCOM server - so I found there is a problem with the Socketservice account (it should not be SYSTEM but a user which can access the network resource)

Comment: No. No need to access the server exe from the client. It's DCOM on the server receieving the request from the client to instantiate the server doing it. There is no need to use a shared drive, it's just a security breach. That way you just end up running the server on the client as a local app stored on a remote drive, everythings runs on the client, no DCOM calls across the network.

Answer (score 1):

1. The server **must not** be in any shared network drive
2. You have to register the server type library on the client side, or DCOM on the client side won't be able to understand what class to instantiate and how to marshall its calls across the network. It is DCOM that will take care of asking the server to instantiate the server application.
3. In the DCOM connection, you have to tell where the server is (IP or host name).
4. DCOM must be configured correctly: use DCOMcnfg.exe to configure which user/groups can instantiate and call the server

If you're using the socket server it actually acts as a proxy. It's the socketserver making the DCOM calls on behalf of the client, but still calls are encapsulated inside the packets sent to the socket server.

Comment: We have no TDCOMConnection component in the client side, only a TSocketConnection - if I understand correctly, Socketserver is not a simple DCOM proxy (which would have the same API as the real DCOM server) but some kind of a tunnelling technology.

Comment: It's not a tunnel because it is actually the socket server that performs the DCOM calls (losing the whole DCOM security implementation). The client identity is lost. Anyway the client still need to know about the DCOM interface, its type library must be registered client side, especially if the application uses early binding. Late binding through IDispatch should work, but the type library should speed up method binding anyway. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Calling_Server_Interfaces

Comment: we never had to register the library on the client side (neither in-house nor on external client computers). The users simply launch the client app and - given that port 211 is open in their firewall - it works, for about ten years now (since MIDAS 1). I guess it is late binding.

Comment: Yes, but it depends on how you code the call client side. If you look at the link I posted above, there is a way to cast the interface to a dispinteface and improve the call speed a bit. IIRC that requires the type library registration. But I stopped using the socket server years ago due its bugs and security issues (basically, anyone can call the server) .

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

- tregsvr the UNC path to the network location of the Datasnap Server (instead of a mounted network drive)
- running Socketserver as SYSTEM account is fine, no additional privileges required

After logging off from the server, the Datasnap client still happily connects with the server

The other/old servers are running the Socketserver as an application with the necessary rights :P

Comment: That works just because registering the server actually registers the type library. You just need to register the server type library, there's no need to have the server .exe accessible from the client. That's what RPC and DCOM is all about.
Anyway running as SYSTEM means any flaw in your server will make it expolitable with one of the most privileged accounts. Good luck.